# How to properly wait for the template to update in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I'm trying to understand the best approach to wait for the template to update in an Angular 2 application after the model has changed.

```
@Component{
   template : `<button type="button" (click)="handleClick()">Click</button>
               <div *ngIf="!hidden">
                   <input type='text' #eleInput/>
               </div>`
}
export class Sample{
   private hidden: boolean = true;
   @ViewChild('eleInput') eleInput: ElementRef;

   constructor(){}

   handleClick(){
      this.hidden = false;

      //nativeElement is undefined here
      this.eleInput.nativeElement.focus();

      //nativeElement is defined here
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.eleInput.nativeElement.focus();
      });
   }
}
```

Using setTimeout in the above code seems hacky, so I'd like to know if there's a better approach.

Thanks!

Comment: Look into [Animations](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html#!#example-entering-and-leaving)...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use **`[hidden]`** instead of **`ngIf`**.
**`NgIf`** removes element. That's the reason `this.eleInput.nativeElement.focus();` doesn't work without `setTimeout` because `this.eleInput.nativeElement.focus();` line runs immediately before DOM element is/becomes set for the further reference.
 
When **`[hidden]`** property doesn't remove DOM element. It just shows and hides an element. So DOM element reference will be there and you nativeElement won't be undefined. So, it will work.

```
<div [hidden]="hidden">                        //<<<===use hidden instead of *ngIf
            <input type='text' #eleInput/>
</div>
```

---

```
private hidden: boolean = true;
   @ViewChild('eleInput') eleInput: ElementRef;

   constructor(){}

   handleClick(){
      this.hidden = false;                      
      this.eleInput.nativeElement.focus();     //<<<===now this will work.
   }
}
```

Comment: This is actually the best approach for this scenario, which I'll use. But I'm still curious if there's a way to handle the *ngIf scenario without a setTimeout

Comment: It's I guess not possible as `*ngIf` removes DOM element and `this.eleInput.nativeElement.focus()` runs immediately before dom element is set correctly. So I think it won't be possible without `setTimeout`

Answer (score 10):

There is no way to wait for the template to update.

You can inject `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
constructor(private cdRef:ChangeDetectorRef) {}
```

and then call

```
this.cdRef.detectChanges();
```

As far as I know the template is updated when the call returns.